# Color of vertical slider of Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qslider

I created Vertical Slider with **Qt Designer**. But, the color fills reverse direction.Like this:

[image]

Should I do to make the color in the correct direction.

Comment: You could display the contents of the generated .ui file.

Comment: try setStyleSheet("handle:horizontal {color: red}"); to see if it's resolve your problem.

Comment: Looks like this old bug in webkit, maybe the proposed patch can solve this for you: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39421

Comment: Thank you. I will use the patch.

Comment: @Hiro Did it work?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a bug that appeared in Webkit several years ago.
The problem only occurs for vertical sliders. You can use the function [sliderValueFromPosition](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstyle.html#sliderValueFromPosition) function to get the value as described in this bugreport: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39421